# Should i put my library dependencies into devDependencies if I only publish the bundle of the library?

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json, dependency-management

If i generate a bundle of a library, should I put the library dependencies in `devDependencies`?

I'm authoring a NPM library written in TypeScript which uses a quite amount of dependencies, such as React components.
We do some build steps to compile down to JavaScript files, apply minification and bundle into a single JS file.
The final published package for this library will contain just a JS file, the output of this build steps.

When I install the package all the dependencies of this library will be installed as well. Should I put those libraries as `devDependencies` instead in the package.json, given that they are not needed because the JS file will already bundle them?

Comment: Will consumers of your library need them installed? If so they should be dependencies or peerDependencies. If not, devDependencies.

Comment: The consumers won't need it as I see it, because those library dependencies are already included in the bundle I'm generating and then publishing. But maybe I'm wrong on some other level, such as I shouldn't bundle or even build the library I'm publishing

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the way you build.

Not needed to put all devdependencies if it is already part of the js file.

If it is going to be only a js file, it can be hosted as CDN file.